# Weblogic wlserver memory setting?

Tags: weblogic

When we start up Weblogic (8.1) from the command line, we’re passing it memory usage arguments of the form “-Xms256m -Xmx1024m” which gives it a GB to play with.

When we’re starting it up from ANT, we’re using a “wlserver” task instead which, I’m guessing, does a live launch of it. What memory parameters is it using then? How I would I tell it to use the 1GB option instead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class `weblogic.ant.taskdefs.management.WLServer` extends `org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java` so it should be possible to give it the same parameters as to java ant task (see http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html).

Answer (score 0):

I thought wldeploy allowed you to deploy a new app to WebLogic:

http://e-docs.bea.com/wls/docs90/programming/wldeploy.html

At least that's the way I've used it.

The max and min memory requirements are set in the startup script, are they not?

Comment: You're right.  I meant wlserver, not wldeploy.  Will edit description.

Comment: wlserver still assumes that you've created the WL domain, which has the environment variables like min and max heap size specified inside.  The Ant task simply executes those, so set the heap size there.  I don't see any such settings in the Ant task.

Comment: Those JVM memory settings are configured in the startWeblogic shell/batch script as opposed to any domain based config.  Does wldeploy run that script?  I assumed it didn't.

Comment: deploy doesn't run the script.  are we back to wldeploy again?  or do you still need wlserver?

Comment: Advice still stands, then.  The memory settings are part of the domain environment.  You don't set them in the ant tasks that I can see.  Default startup scripts: http://edocs.bea.com/wls/docs81/perform/JVMTuning.html#1131054